# Oracle setup.exe space sensitivity when specifying jre absolute path

Tags: java, oracle, installation, javaw

I am currently setting up Oracle Enterprise edition for my computer. That means I use the Oracle Universal Installer to launch the program. When I launch the `setup.exe` file from my computer and give the specified arguments:

```
setup.exe -jreLoc "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Program\bin\javaw.exe was not found.
```

However if I copy the `jre7` directory over to the `C:\` directory so the path is now `C:\jre7` then it works. I tried with quotes and it thinks its part of the path file. Single quotes fail as well.

My questions is for the Oracle `setup.exe` launcher how do you specify a space in the path of the `jreLoc` since quotes seem to fail?

Comment: It works without quotes for me, slightly oddly; this is in Windows 7. Have you tried that? Failing that, does using `progra~1` instead of `program files` work?

Comment: You may want to look at My Oracle Support document 1139705.1.  It applies to the installation directory, not the JRE path.  But the moral of the story is that Oracle's installers are a pain, just be glad you found a work-around.  Spaces and tildes are bad characters appearently.

Comment: When I changed "program files" to "progra~1" it worked. Thank you I will post that as an answer just in case someone else has the same problem

Comment: @AlexPoole I love you man :) . Your suggestion works ! for me when I changed `Program files` to `progra~1` installer start working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing "Program Files" to "progra~1" worked as suggested in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Also the directory path containing the installation software should not contain spaces either.  So, for instance move the directory winx64_12c_client to c:\

Answer (score 0):

Consider having the oracle setup files which you are trying to install in a path, where its folders' and subfolders' names DO NOT have spaces..

This worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I used JDK path instead of JRE path and it worked for me, e.g.

```
setup.exe -jreLoc C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk7
```